# How to manually sign Kali for UEFI

Tags: uefi, kali-linux, code-signing

I have a laptop running Win10Pro and has UEFI. I have a USB stick with Kali on it.

If I disable Secure Boot, I can boot from Kali with no problem, but then Win10/BitLocker complains. Naturally, I cannot boot with Secure Boot because Kali is not signed.

How can I manually sign *my* Kali so I can make it boot that way? I'm definitely not above signing it myself with a custom key then telling UEFI to trust that key... if that's possible.

Comment: @ramhound Unless UEFI can let me add a new trusted key

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to use [Linux Foundation signed PreLoader](https://blog.hansenpartnership.com/linux-foundation-secure-boot-system-released/) which works on file hash basis and does not require any configuration, but it will require manual intervention every time you update the kernel.

The proper way is to [generate your own self-signed signing key](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Secure_Boot#Using_your_own_keys), enroll it into UEFI and sign bootloader and kernel with it.

Another way is to use one of signed shims available (I prefer [Fedora version](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/shim-x64)) with your own self-signed key and kernel, which you don't want/can't enroll into UEFI.

Or, if you don't need "secure" part of Secure Boot, you can use [Super UEFIinSecureBoot Disk](https://github.com/ValdikSS/Super-UEFIinSecureBoot-Disk) bootloader.