# How to install Kali Linux with Linux Foundation PreLoader?

Tags: windows-10, debian, lenovo-laptop, kali-linux, secure-boot

I installed the latest Kali Linux on my notebook Lenovo X390 Yoga. I have dualboot with default installed Windows 10 x64. I need use Bitlocker for Windows 10 partition (I use it without TPM, only with extended password). Kali Linux unfortunately still does not support SecureBoot although Debian 10 Buster yes. :-( So I disabled Secure Boot in bios. But I was unpleasantly surprised that BitLocker with Windows 10 cannot be used without SecureBoot.

So I have to disabled SecureBoot every time when I run KaliLinux and enable every time when I run Windows 10.

I have question what way I can enable SecureBoot for Grub - Kali Linux. Is possible use some package from Debian 10? Or what way I can use Linux Foundation's PreLoader? https://blog.hansenpartnership.com/l...stem-released/ and http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloa...html#preloader 
I have found possible solution from @ValdikSS [How to manually sign Kali for UEFI](https://superuser.com/questions/1427535/how-to-manually-sign-kali-for-uefi) so I have tried https://askubuntu.com/questions/5947...ons-preloader# but after reboot I do not see PreLoader boot option. :-( Can you help me please?

Disk structure:

```
NAME                MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1             259:0    0   477G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1         259:1    0   260M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2         259:2    0    16M  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p3         259:3    0 243,3G  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p4         259:4    0  1000M  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p5         259:5    0   954M  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p6         259:6    0   954M  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p7         259:7    0   954M  0 part  /boot
└─nvme0n1p8         259:8    0 229,6G  0 part  
  └─nvme0n1p8_crypt 254:0    0 229,6G  0 crypt 
    ├─sk1-swap      254:1    0   4,2G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    └─sk1-system    254:2    0 225,4G  0 lvm   /
```

structure of /boot/EFI partition:

```
├── BOOT
│   └── BOOT.SDI
├── EFI
│   ├── Boot <--- here I copied HashTool.efi, PreLoader.efi, loader.efi 
│   │   ├── bootx64.efi
│   │   ├── HashTool.efi
│   │   ├── LenovoBT.EFI
│   │   ├── License.txt
│   │   ├── loader.efi
│   │   ├── PreLoader.efi
│   │   └── ReadMe.txt
│   ├── kali
│   │   └── grubx64.efi
│   ├── Microsoft

loader.efi is renamed grubx64.efi
```

Many thanks.

Comment: IMO Kali is not a real operating system it's more a tool, thats why its lacking in so many arias. to make booting eazy (depending on what you want to do with the system) you can change windows to boot unsecurely in legacy mode (there is a why to swap over). or use kali in a VM.

Comment: Thanks, but I need use it this way.

Comment: I am afraid you will not get your question answered, see: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5361/370891

Comment: @dirdi It is not only about Kali Linux but about Linux Foundation PreLoader too.

Answer (score 0):

> but after reboot I do not see PreLoader boot option

You either need to add it manually using `efibootmgr` or replace real grub (`grubx64.efi` in your case I think) with `PreLoader.efi`.

Anyway, use `efibootmgr` to check your current UEFI boot configuration and alter it if needed.

Comment: many thanks. What way I can manually alter my current UEFI boot configuration please? efibootmgr --verbose does not show Linux Foundation PreLoader now.

Comment: I successfully added PreLoader, but Klai Linux does not boot I get this error and it runs GRUB rescue mode: `error: secure boot forbids loading module from (hd0,gpt7)/grub/x86_64-efi/normal.mod.` Any idea please?